# Store Reference Data Mulesoft

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have a reference data stored in one set variable component and the value is like this :

```
[{
  "subjectId": "0001",
  "subjectName": "Subject 1"
 },
 {
  "subjectId": "0002",
  "subjectName": "Subject 2"
 },
 {
  "subjectId": "0003",
  "subjectName": "Subject 3"
 }
]
```

Is there a more optimal way to store this. Database reference is not an option and might need to update this reference data in the future if new subject is created. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try Object Store using the initial configuration as the default value?

Comment: Why storing the data in a database is not an option? Please provide more context. And what criteria are you using for more optimal? Easy of update, performance, something else?

Comment: There is no owner of the data and it will be used only for mapping. I know about object store but can it be used for this use case. Isnt it for storing temp data like access token?

Answer (score 0):

There is no optimal answer. If you want to avoid having fixed data in a flow you can try to read it from a YAML file as properties configuration.

You can alternatively use also a JSON file and use the File connector, or parse-template to read it into a variable. In this case you could use a cache scope to avoid reading the file more than once. Once read you can store into a variable, object store, database, etc.